# How to change urls to one of the model's property?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, url-routing

Let me explain what I want very easy:
I have a model named `Section`.My section model has a property named `UrlSafe`.I am showing my urlsafes in the url now.It means my urls is like this:

```
www.test.com/section/show/(the section's urlsafe goes here)
```

But what I want to do now is to remove `section/show` from the url.I want to make it like this:

```
www.test.com/(my section's urlsafe)
```

More informations:

1- I am working under MVC3

2- My model is like this:

```
public class Section
{
    public int SectionId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string MetaTag { get; set; }
    public string MetaDescription { get; set; }
    public string UrlSafe { get; set; }
    public string Header { get; set; }
    public string ImageName { get; set; }
}
```

3- My links are like this:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Show", "Section", new { sectionUrl = sectionItem.UrlSafe }, null)">@sectionItem.Name</a>
```

4- My controller is something like the following:

```
public ActionResult Show(string sectionUrl)
{
    var section = sectionApp.GetSectionBySectionUrl(sectionUrl);
    return View(section);
}
```

5- And finally I have these line in Global.asax:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Section",
    url: "{controller}/show/{sectionUrl}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Section", action = "Show", sectionUrl = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{name}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", name = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

What is your solution?

Thanks.

Comment: I want to help you out but I am having a bit of a tough time working out some of the finer details of your problem. Are the controller and action stored in the URL in your model? When you have the url test.com/(urlsafe), what controller/action do you wish to reach? I've put a temporary response there to get you started, but I'll refine it if you can provide me with further details.

Comment: No.My model's urlsafe doesnt contains controller and action name.And when the request is test.com/(urlsafe) I want to call section controller and its show action but I dont want to see them in the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle you just need to change this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Section",
    url: "{controller}/show/{sectionUrl}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Section", action = "Show", sectionUrl =
        UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

to this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Section",
    url: "{sectionUrl}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Section", action = "Show" }
);
```

Note that I have removed the default value from the `sectionurl` component. This is important, because if `sectionurl` is optional, then visiting test.com will direct you to Section/Show, because the parameterless URL will match that route. Making this parameter mandatory means that only urls with a single segment will match this pattern. This may still cause problems, but at least visiting test.com will still take you to your homepage.

### Disclaimer

**Messing with routing can have serious implications on how the rest of your application functions. In particular, it could seriously break navigation to existing pages.**

I strongly recommend you to take another look at what you are doing and see if there isn't a better way to achieve the desired result. Without knowing the context, I must say that storing a URL in a model parameter doesn't seem like a very good idea.

Comment: You **really** need to read more about routes. They are very powerful (and as with great power comes great responsibility) can can wreak havoc on your application's navigation system if used incorrectly. I assume that the problem is because you don't have a default route defined (again, read up on routes and the prioritization and selection of routes to get a better feel for the subject). The object reference error is strange though. You'll have to post some code.

Comment: I had default route but it was giving me error.But after I changed my code to your answer update it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Section",
    url: "{sectionUrl}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Section", action = "Show", sectionUrl =     UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Totally agree with @Levi Botelho comments